# OpenSearch not working in Firefox: "Firefox could not download the search plugin from"

Tags: opensearch

While testing to ensure OpenSearch works for my site I receive the error, "Firefox could not download the search plugin from:" after clicking the search provider to add it to Firefox.

Here is the source for my OpenSearch looks like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
<ShortName>Example</ShortName>
<Description>Search www.example.com</Description>
<Image height="16" width="16" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">http://www.example.com/favicon.ico</Image>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
<Url method="get" template="http://www.example.com/search/?q={searchTerms}&#38;source=opensearch" type="application/xhtml+xml" />
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

What am I doing wrong that is generating this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No text/html Url element:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox

> Note that you must include a text/html URL — search plugins including
>   only Atom or RSS URL types (which is valid, but Firefox doesn't
>   support) will also generate the "could not download the search plugin"
>   error.

I've just had the same problem myself!

Comment: I'll accept that answer, reasonably close enough. Firefox does NOT correctly support XHTML (application/xhtml+xml) with OpenSearch and I filed a bug report on Bugzilla. *sigh* Thanks!

Comment: Here's a link to the bug report in question: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=871394

Comment: Additionally, OpenSearch descriptions should be served with `Content-Type: application/opensearchdescription+xml`.