# Firefox could not install the search engine from…

Tags: firefox, opensearch

I'm trying to make [APLcart](https://aplcart.info/) work with OpenSearch, but keep getting `Firefox could not install the search engine from: https://aplcart.info/opensearch.xml` with:

```html
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="APLcart" 
href="/opensearch.xml">
```

Where [`/opensearch.xml`](https://aplcart.info/opensearch.xml) is:

```xml
<OpenSearchDescription>
<ShortName>APLcart</ShortName>
<Description>
Search APLcart: A novel approach to finding your way in APL
</Description>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
<Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">https://aplcart.info/favicon.ico</Image>
<Url type="text/html" template="https://aplcart.info/?q={searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

- Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16502011/5306507) is not the same issue, since I *do* have `Url type="text/html"`.
- I've tried with `method="get"`

**What do I need to change for my OpenSearch specification to be compliant?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the correct namespace

```
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
```

If you open the browser console (CTRL+Shift+J) you can see the error message

> Invalid search plugin due to namespace not matching.

Comment: Well they do have that. See for example `view-source:https://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realise at first that Firefox hides XML attributes in the "nice" default view.